# How does oracle estimate the space required for a bulk insert

Tags: oracle

When I do a bulk insert in an oracle db, (e.g 1 million rows), before starting the insert ,does oracle calculate how much space is required for the new rows and somehow 'block' that space so no other process can insert anything in that space?

Comment: Are you asking about a direct-path insert?  Or a conventional-path insert?

Comment: Um...can you give an answer for both?

Comment: The short answer is "no". It'll happily start inserting rows until it runs out of room, then rollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You'll run into `ORA-01653: unable to extend table xxx by yyy in tablespace zzz`

You'd have to compute this manually and create large enough initial and/or next extents using the `storage` clause.

Refer to the [Oracle documentation of Conventional and Direct Path Loads](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_modes.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer discussed by [ASKTOM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2007/07-may/o37asktom-101781.html): A Must Read**

Comment: I do not want to copy the content. Hence posted URL as an answer, as a single line